# Is there any way possible to Undo a Join Request to a team, on Launchpad.net?

Tags: launchpad

Is there any way possible to Undo a Join Request to a team, on Launchpad.net ?
it happens that I request to join a team by mistake, I thought it was the team responsible for the job I wanted to contribute to, but found it's not, and in fact I had no reply from team admin. in this case someone can just add me, by my former request, while I changed my mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you're added you can immediately leave a group on Launchpad, if you wish to not be part of it.  There is currently no way to withdraw a request yourself, but you can always wait until the membership is processed and then leave immediately.